# Get existing IE via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

My goal is to scrape data off multiple webpages on the same site into Excel. I have these pages open in tabs within IE8. I have no other IE windows open.

I have tried the following to open IE:

```
AppActivate "Microsoft Internet Explorer provided by [my company]"
' It loses focus, the titlebar flashes for a fraction of a second 
' .. another code ..
Dim ShellApp
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim ShellWindows
Set ShellWindows = ShellApp.Windows()
Dim i
For i = 0 To ShellWindows.Count - 1
    If InStr(ShellWindows.Item(i).FullName, "iexplore.exe") <> 0 Then
        Set IEObject = ShellWindows.Item(i) 
    End If
Next
' Did absolutely nothing, grabbed this code from another solution on stackoverflow
```

I also tried GetObject (I do not want to use the CreateObject method) as follows

```
dim ie As InternetExplorer 'also tried As Object and other variation
set ie = GetObject(, "InternetExplorer.Application")
'However this is not workable due to security risks and Microsoft 
' disabled GetObject for IE by design.
```

The reason I don't want to use CreateObject or any of the variation is because I already have the tabs open ready to be scraped. AppActivate works with Microsoft Excel, but not IE. I cannot do exact titlebars as follows:

```
AppActivate "Website name - name page - Microsoft Internet Explorer provided by [my company]"
```

The reason I can't use this because of the tabs with varying named pages, changing the title constantly. I also tried:

```
AppActivate InternetExplorer.Application

AppActivate InternetExplorer

AppActivate " - Microsoft Internet Explorer"

AppActivate "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
```

All of the above either are not recognized or merely flash for a fraction of a second (as mentioned in first code). I have tried other methods but they create a new IE instance when I want to use the existing IE with opened multi-tabs.

In a different code:

```
AppActivate "[name of page] - Microsoft Internet Explorer provided by [my company]"
```

worked until I changed it to try and reference IE, no matter what page I'm on. Then the old AppActivate code will no longer work. I broke it. It was dumb of me to not have a back up.

System I am running:

Windows 7, IE8 (I'm waiting on my company to upgrade), Excel 2010

Comment: you getting runtime error 5? I can only use the `AppActivate` function when the specific tab name *is* the one with focus (Win 7, IE10). It fails otherwise with that error.  Have you had a look at the Selenium Wrapper?  I have not used it with IE but I *have* used it briefly with Google Chrome and Firefox, it seems to be a more robust solution and natively supports tabbed browsing. Might be worth spending a few minutes to check it out.  https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/

Comment: I'm not getting any runtime errors except when I tried doing the GetObject method and gave me the ActiveX error, hence finding out that Microsoft disabled it. As for Selenium Wrapper--it sounds like a dream! //strikeout//I hope it will do what I want it to do. I'll let you know how it goes.\\strikeout\\ Unfortunately, I can't install it due to company restrictions. It will take awhile to get it installed, if I even get the permission to do so. In the meantime, any other workarounds?

Comment: Do you really have "company restrictions" on installing third-party libraries? If so, they are basically saying, "Here is a spoon, go dig the foundation for a skyscraper".  What you need is a more powerful tool, if they will not let you have one it is probably a knee-jerk reaction. Lay out the case for it, and seek permission. They'll probably grant it.

Comment: As for other suggestions, no, I have never tried to work with tabbed browser in IE automation, precisely because it either seemed impossible, or not worth the effort when other libraries let me do it easily in other browsers :)

Comment: Thank you David for helping out! I will definitely try to get SW installed. As for tabbed browser, it isn't so much with tabs themselves but the entire browser. I'm using sendkeys to manipulate tabs so that's no problem.

Comment: OK, so you just need to get a handle on IE?  I think I see a problem with one of your methods.  Give me a few minutes...

Answer (score 4):

A compressed combination of the above answers, here's what works for me.

---

## `GetIE` Function

(No references required.)

```
Function GetIE() As Object
'return an object for the open Internet Explorer window, or create new one
  For Each GetIE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows() 'Loop to find
    If (Not GetIE Is Nothing) And GetIE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then Exit For 'Found!
  Next GetIE
  If GetIE Is Nothing Then Set GetIE=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'Create
  GetIE.Visible = True 'Make IE window visible
End Function
```

### Example Usage:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = GetIE                                        'get new/existing IE object
    ie.Navigate "http://stackoverflow.com", 2             '2=don't keep history
    Do: DoEvents: Loop While ie.Busy or ie.ReadyState <> 4'wait til loaded
    Stop                                                  'do your stuff
    ie.Quit                                               'close IE
    Set ie = Nothing                                      'clean up
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Made some changes and it works now:

```
Function GetIE() As Object

    Dim ShellApp As Object, ShellWindows As Object
    Dim IEObject As Object

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    Set ShellWindows = ShellApp.Windows()

    Dim item As Object
    On Error GoTo 0
    Dim sName As String
       
       For Each ObjWind In ShellWindows
        'On Error Resume Next
         If (Not ObjWind Is Nothing) Then
            sName = ObjWind.Name
             If sName = "Internet Explorer" Then
                Set IEObject = ObjWind
                Exit For  'No need to continue....
             End If
         End If

        Next
        
    If IEObject Is Nothing Then Set IEObject = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    Set GetIE = IEObject

End Function
```

Comment: Verified! Great Job.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I notice a potential problem with the first method you attempt using the Shell object.

You may have an incorrect value for the `.FullName` property.  (when I debug and examin the `ShellWindows` collection, I see path `""C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\"`

```
Function GetIE() As Object

Dim ShellApp as Object, ShellWindows as Object, i as Long 
Dim IEObject As Object

Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set ShellWindows = ShellApp.Windows()

For i = 0 To ShellWindows.Count - 1
    If InStr(ShellWindows.Item(i).FullName, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE") <> 0 Then
       Set IEObject = ShellWindows.Item(i)
       Exit For  'No need to continue....
    End If
Next

If IEObject Is Nothing Then Set IEObject = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Set GetIE = IEObject

End Function
```

You can put this function in your code, just tuck it away somewhere, then whenever you need IE you can call it like:

Comment: I tried the function code, and it gave me the following error: "Invalid procedure call or argument." for the following line: `If InStr(ShellWindows.Item(i).FullName, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe") <> 0 Then`

Comment: That is perplexing because it is the exact same code that you said you previously used,  just a different string comparison. Nothing about that statement should raise an error if it didn't raise an error before.

Comment: It is... I tripled checked to make sure I'm not getting errors in the original script, and I'm not. It just does nothing. I guess I'll create a new object (IE) and then open favorites or older session to open all tabs. Not ideal, but it'll do. Thank you so much David for helping! I am definitely planning on getting the SW IDE. It sounds like the answer I've been searching for. I do a lot of data scraping at work.

Comment: I got it! See answer in [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b5a5efe-d083-450f-9624-b2f72893fe9d/bring-window-to-front-appactivate-does-not-help-?forum=ITCG), the following works:

Comment: Er, I meant to write that comment into the Answer post for this thread, and to tell you that I figured it out. :)

Comment: Good work! If my answer has been helpful, do consider upvoting it you and I both get a few magical internet points as a result :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [to this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b5a5efe-d083-450f-9624-b2f72893fe9d/bring-window-to-front-appactivate-does-not-help-?forum=ITCG), the following works:

```
AppActivate " - Microsoft Internet Explorer provided by [my company]"
AppActivate " - Microsoft Internet Explorer provided by [my company]"
```

And it is able to bring forward any site, no matter the naming scheme. Granted, it looks clumsy, but I can't complain if it works.

Comment: This doesn't get the ie *object*.