# Navigate to new URL in existing Internet Explorer window

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, window

I am trying to get an existing (open) IE window to load a new URL via `ie.Navigate`.

Below is my worksheet code which loads a website on click of a button:

```
Private Sub Sendit_Click()
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.yahoo.com"
    Do
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    GetIE

    Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is in my module:

```
Function GetIE()
    Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer

    Set shellWins = New ShellWindows

    If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
        ' Get IE
        Set IE = shellWins.Item(0)
    Else
        ' Create IE
        Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        IE.Visible = True
    End If

    IE.navigate "http://www.google.com"

    Set shellWins = Nothing
    Set IE = Nothing
End Function
```

IE doesn't navigate to http://www.google.com.

Comment: `IE.navigate "http://www.google.com"`

Comment: Thanks Tim, that helped solved that part, but now it highlights to getIE = True, i'm familiar with PHP and calling function from there, but am i doing the call right in VBA?

Comment: You can't assign a value to a function - I'm not clear what you mean to do with that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub TestGetIE()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.yahoo.com"
    WaitFor IE

    Set IE = GetIE("https://www.yahoo.com")

    IE.navigate "http://www.google.com"


End Sub

Sub WaitFor(IE)
    Do
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End Sub


Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim retVal As Object

    Set retVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        'check the URL and if it's the one you want then
        ' assign it to the return value
        sURL = o.LocationURL
        If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
            Set retVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = retVal

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, got close, but what i want is to have the existing opened IE window to go to the new URL yahoo.com, which i found from some other discussion is the code i posted above as the function.

Comment: That's exactly what that did when I ran it.

Answer (score 2):

As a similar/adapted alternative, here's a favorite function of mine.

This function returns an object representing the *existing* `InternetExplorer` instance if there is one, otherwise a *newly-created* instance.

```
Function GetIE() As Object
'return an object for the open Internet Explorer window, or create new one
  For Each GetIE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows() 'Loop to find
    If (Not GetIE Is Nothing) And GetIE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then Exit For 'Found!
  Next GetIE
  If GetIE Is Nothing Then Set GetIE=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")'Create
  GetIE.Visible = True 'Make IE window visible
End Function
```

More information and example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348077/8112776).

Comment: (obviously, you need to have Internet Explorer installed on your machine in order for this to function)