# VBA excel fireevent "onclick" return IE.ReadyState

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble with the a certain onclick event, i got my VBA to use the

```
Dim div As HTMLDivElement
Set div = IE.document.getElementById("btn_header")

div.FireEvent "onclick"
IE.Quit

Do
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
```

to do the onclick event on

```
<td>
<div id='btn_header' title='BTN' onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"></div>
```

Which did the job perfectly by opening google.com in a new tab and close the tab before it but then it got stuck at the Loop, as if the site is never ready, hence i did a debug test

```
Debug.Print IE.document.Title
```

The debug still shows the site title of the previous page with the button instead of google.com, any help?

Comment: Google loads in a new browser window, so you can't keep using your old `IE` reference to work with that page (particularly since you Quit the previous window)- you will need to get a reference to the new window.  Here's one approach for doing that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167200/excel-vba-new-url-on-existing-ie/31169311#31169311

Comment: Just realized the question I linked to was one of your previous ones....

Comment: Didn't know i had to do that to achieve that result, thanks again