# Run my VBA code from a existing (opened) internet explorer page

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I would like to run my VBA macro on a specific internet explorer page that **I have already opened and logged into** .

This is because I have to login to my account and bypass the captcha code first.
I have to send this extremely repetitive message to over a couple hundred people over the course of the year.

Problem with the following is that I am opening up a brand new page and I wont be able to bypass the captcha.

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.navigate ("website")

  IE.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Solution

```
Sub TestGetIE()

    Dim IE As Object
    
    'GetIE runs the Functoin we have created below
    Set IE = GetIE("website opened in IE here ")
    WaitFor IE

end sub 

Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim retVal As Object

    Set retVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
    'Loop through all the opened internet explorer pages
        sURL = ""
        'Loops through all the pages opened on internet explorer
        'Then we will tell our macro to work on that page
        sURL = o.LocationURL
        If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
            Set retVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = retVal
    

End Function
```

Comment: You can find each existing IE window and check its URL to find the one you want, and then work with that window - eg. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167200/navigate-to-new-url-in-existing-internet-explorer-window/31169311#31169311

Comment: @TimWilliams Thankyou got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling upon this function helped me solve it.

```
Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim retVal As Object

    Set retVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
    'Loop through all the opened internet explorer pages
        sURL = ""
        'Loops through all the pages opened on internet explorer
        'Then we will tell our macro to work on that page
        sURL = o.LocationURL
        If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
            Set retVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = retVal
    

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is DoEvents until a certain Element is present on the page. Run your code to navigate to the website, then Do Until Element after captcha is present DoEvents. The code will loop until you are on logged into the website. I like using VBA SeleniumBasic ChromeDriver on GetHub. It makes web scraping way easier, and you do not need to use Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I understand that you want user interaction to fill the captcha and then want to continue to automate the same page.

I suggest you for both steps try to use 2 different modules and use the same IE object in both modules.

You can create a global IE object which you can use in both modules.

Then for the login part execute the first module.

After that user will fill the captcha manually.

Then execute the second module to automate the rest of the page.

Sample code:

```
Public ie As Object

Sub login()

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "Your_web_site_URL_here..."
    
     Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    ie.document.getElementById("uname").Value = "user1"
    ie.document.getElementById("pswd").Value = "12345"
    
End Sub

Sub second_part()
   ie.document.getElementById("email").Value = "user1@abc.com"
   ie.document.getElementById("age").Value = "30"
End Sub
```

UserForm1 code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Module1.login
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call Module1.second_part
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]