# Cannot fill text box in internet explorer via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I used `IE.Document.getelementbyID("tinymce").value= "test"`

Tested with `Element = IE.Document.getelementbyid("tinymce")` shows `null` in locals window

Not able to enter text into this textbox on internet explorer via vba

[image: .]

[Iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU8tu.png)

[image: HTML]

Comment: HTML is a language that can be used to express instructions how to write code. The IE.Document is a document containing such instructions. You can edit it with a text editor. Look upon an element at like a paragraph of such a document. What you have downloaded, therefore, isn't a textbox but the instruction how another program, one that can interpret HTML, would create a textbox. You can read and modify the instruction but you are nowhere near a textbox.

Comment: In addition to what Variatus wrote. You show an HTML snippet that is inside an iFrame. This means that you are working on an HTML document that was loaded after the URL you specified was loaded. So you have to use `.document.frames` and reference the correct iFrame via it' index and then access the document inside.

Comment: @Variatus hmm, not sure if I follow. Kind of new to this VBA stuff. What are you are saying is that the codes there is how the (possibly using) HTML created the textbox. So the face that I am referencing my code to that is completely useless and irrelevant. In this case do you have any suggestions on how I reference the text box and fill it with information from my excel?

Comment: Please work on your question. It's not clear whether you want to modify the textbox on the web or whether you want a textbox in your worksheet.

Comment: From your description, I understand that you want to assign value to the textbox on the webpage. In your VBA code, you are trying to set the value of the element that has an id **tinymce**. If you see your HTML code then you can notice that it is a body tag and not a textbox. so you are not referring to the textbox. I suggest you right-click on the textbox and select the **Inspect element** option. It will take you to the code for that textbox. It may help to locate that element properly and then you can try to modify your VBA code.

Comment: Another thing I want to suggest to you is that If you got the solution for your [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074588/run-my-vba-code-from-a-existing-opened-internet-explorer-page) then try to post the solution and mark your solution. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Comment: @Zwenn I think I may have found the iframe you are talking about. thanks

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Oh I didnt know there was a answer your question button below. Thanks

Comment: @jonathan, Is there any textbox in the iframe? In the iframe code, I can just see the `<p>` tag which contains text 'testing'. Can you also try to show the picture of that textbox? Did you try the **inspect element** option with that textbox? Did you see the code for the textbox?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I added it under the picture HTML.

Comment: Based on the picture, I understand that you want to set the message body for that mail. Correct me if I am wrong. I suggest you try to refer to this [code example](https://justpaste.it/2ghhb) that may help to set the text inside the message body. Let us know about your test results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT This works! If you post the solution I can mark it. Thanks

Comment: @jonathan, I have posted the answer. you can accept the answer. thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the picture, I understand that you want to set the message body for that mail. Correct me if I am wrong. I suggest you try to refer to this code example that may help to set the text inside the message body.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
       
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://Your_URL_here..."

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set Doc = IE.document
    Set frame = Doc.frames("messageBody_ifr").document
    Set para = frame.getElementsByTagName("p")(0)
    para.innerHTML = "This is my sample text..."
     
End Sub
```