# Excel VBA Reference issue

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation, reference

Not sure why I am getting the issue I am. Starting off, I am learning how to use excel VBA to go into my companies websites to consolidate data and build out quick reports that take hours to do manually.

In doing so I ran across tutorials that show you how to load webpages and find and assign elements values. The problem I am having is that the script isn't finding the items on the web pages. I am suspecting it's the ie.document portion of the script, but can't find any relevant information for this.

I started off using the link at the bottom for a youtube video. While troubleshooting I used the top link to see if adding the HTMLDocument element would fix the issue. Which it didn't. I quadruple checked the reference libraries and I am lost. Every tutorial I have seen goes through the same things and this seems god awfully simple. Even in the comment section there is no reference to the issues I am seeing.

Script below:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim ie As Object
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://atmchome.freescale.net/"
    
    'Do While ie.Busy
        'Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    'Loop
    
    Dim oHDoc As HTMLDocument     ' Create document object.
    Set oHDoc = ie.document
    
    ie.document.getElementById("mod_fs_search_searchword").Value = "Test"


End Sub
```

Websites referenced:
https://www.encodedna.com/excel/extract-contents-from-html-element-of-a-webpage-in-excel-using-vba.htm
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6HRjiAdW38

Comment: Does your machine still have Internet Explorer installed?  At some point, Windows Update replaced IE with Edge on my laptop, and now, any of [my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56181681/8112776) tried-and-tested code that uses `InternetExplorer` doesn't run. (Error #429: `ActiveX component can't create object`)  I don't have a need for it currently so I haven't bothered looking into it further.  Maybe there's a new API (and VBA reference) for Edge? I have no idea. Nowadays for any ad-hoc needs for web data, I've shifted to using JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 will be retired and go out of support in June 2022 "for certain versions of Windows 10" ([source](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/))

Comment: Especially given that IE support will be ending, I would suggest you try to build your application using Power Query, available in Excel 2010+.  It should be useful for a longer period of time.

Comment: what is the error message and on which line? You don't have an active page load wait so assignment likely occurs before load completed.