# How can I change this statement to add another If?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to find an active "Internet Explorer" window and interact with it. I am trying to add a message box popup if the user does not have an internet explorer window open, as opposed to just getting a VBA error. Here is my current code:

```
For Each GetIE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows() 'Loop to find
If (Not GetIE Is Nothing) And GetIE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then Exit For 'Found!
Next GetIE
```

And what I want to add is essentially:

```
If Not GetIE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
MsgBox ("You do not have an active Internet Explorer window open")
End IF
```

But when I added that right below the first code it did not work and gave me an error.  I did not write the top section and unsure how to change it to implement the messagebox. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get existing IE via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897956/get-existing-ie-via-vba)

Comment: @braX Yes I was able to figure it out from that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, please:

```
Sub testFindIE()
 Dim GetIE As Object, boolFound As Boolean
 For Each GetIE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows()
    If (Not GetIE Is Nothing) And GetIE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
        boolFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
 Next GetIE
 If Not boolFound Then MsgBox "You do not have an active Internet Explorer window open"
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly does boolFound do? I actually just added If GetIE is Nothing Then MsgBox ("xxx") and it worked. Why would i use boolFound instead?  Also, thank you so much for the reply!

Comment: @Lzypenguin: `boolFound` is a boolean variable (`True` of `False`). It is 'born' `False`. If the IE window exists, it takes `True` value. And then, according to its value, the message it is sent, or not...

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Lzypenguin: Glad I could help you!