# Target existing IE window tab using VBA

Tags: vba, object, internet-explorer

### I'm trying to target an existing IE window (one tab only) with my script.

In other words: there's an Internet Explorer window opened with a specific tab and I'm trying to get my script to target that tab using its tab name.
I had a look at these topics, but none worked for me (or I did it wrong):

- [Get existing IE via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897956/get-existing-ie-via-vba)
- [Navigate to new URL in existing Internet Explorer window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167200/navigate-to-new-url-in-existing-internet-explorer-window)
- [VBA Macro For Already Open IE Window](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-macro-for-already-open-ie-window.553580/#post-2733743)

Therefore I created this (**which worked for a while** until I got a 438 Error for no reason) :

```
Sub FindingExistingIE()

Dim Application As Object
Dim ApplicationWindows As Object
Dim WindowTitle As Variant
Dim TargetWindow As Object

Set Application = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set ApplicationWindows = Application.Windows

For Each Application In ApplicationWindows
    WindowTitle = Application.Document.Title
    If WindowTitle Like "IE Window Title" Then
        Set TargetWindow = Application
        Exit For
    End If
Next Application

NextSub TargetWindow

End
End Sub
```

As I said, the script worked fine for a week but now I get the 438 error:

[image: Error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method]

> Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)

The error highlights the following line:

```
WindowTitle = Application.Document.Title
```

---

Having read the [Microsoft Doc related to the error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-doesn-t-support-this-property-or-method-error-438), I tried changing the *WindowTitle* variable to an object. Didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: My answer here has always worked fine for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167200/navigate-to-new-url-in-existing-internet-explorer-window   The Shell `Windows` collection also includes Windows Explorer windows, which do not have a `Document` property, so you have to handle that case.

Comment: I replaced the `.Document.Title` by `.Name` and now I have a different error! The 91 error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me - finds IE by looking for an open window with the passed URL:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim w As Object
    
    Set w = FindingExistingIEByUrl("https://www.google.com")
    If Not w Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox w.document.Title
    Else
        MsgBox "No IE window found"
    End If
End Sub


Function FindingExistingIEByUrl(theUrl)
    Dim w As Object
    For Each w In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        'Debug.Print w.locationurl
        If w.locationurl Like theUrl & "*" Then
            Set FindingExistingIEByUrl= w
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next w
End Function


Function FindingExistingIEByTitle(theTitle)
    Dim w As Object, t As String
    For Each w In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        t = ""
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no Document
        t = w.Document.Title
        On Error Goto 0
        If t Like theTitle Then
            Set FindingExistingIEByTitle = w
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next w
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I'm trying to use the tab name instead of the URL since the latter changes every time I'm running the script

Comment: See `FindingExistingIEByTitle` added above - maybe try that.

Comment: Tim, do you know why the script does not work without the error handler? It works fine with it, but I get the error 438 without.

Comment: See my first comment under your question